# Wordpress - enabling JS in local running instance

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am relatively new to Wordpress.

I have two instances of Wordpress - one running on a server in prod, and the other the same exact copy that I've downloaded from the server, but running locally.

A problem I'm trying to figure out is - the one on the server is loading all the necessary JS files within the theme. However, my local running instance is only loading JS files **outside** the theme.

In addition, I've noticed in my local running instance - there's a `no-js` class added to the `<html>` tag, whereas this is missing in the prod instance. This leads me to believe there must be some sort of switch on the theme itself, or somewhere in the wordpress admin panel that enables or disables JS.

For some context, I'm using the minimal minimum theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/minimum-minimal/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was preventing the JS from loading - I forgot to include `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`
within the footer - which loads in all the remaining necessary JS, in particular if they've been imported with via `wp_enqueue_script` with `in_footer` arg set to `true`